# Is it ok to enforce a dual-licensing clause in a copyright header?

Tags: dual-license

For a piece of software for which I am the sole author, I would like to dual-license it with AGPLv3 and proprietary.

To my knowledge, this is ok and actually quite common.

Additionally, I wish is to:

- enforce the proprietary licensee to push direct changes toward the open-source community. This is quite easy, just by adding a clause to the proprietary license.
- enforce the open-source community to provide **direct** changes with this same dual-licensing. I was thinking of some code header like this following one:

```
/*
 * Copyright [Year] [My name - contact]
 *
 * Dual License Notice:
 * This file is part of [Library project] and is licensed under two 
 * distinct licenses:
 * 1. Affero General Public License (AGPL) version 3.
 * 2. Proprietary License.
 *
 * You may choose to use this file under either of the above-mentioned licenses.
 * 
 * If you choose to use this file under the AGPL version 3, you must
 * comply with the terms of that license. Additionally, you agree to include 
 * this exact dual licensing notice with any direct derivative of this 
 * library (defined as any modification, enhancement, extension, 
 * or other alteration of this library source code, where mere usage is excluded). 
 *
 * If you choose to use this file under the Proprietary License, you must
 * comply with the terms of that license as agreed upon with [My name].
 *
 * For more information on the AGPL license, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */
```

This is to avoid divergence between the proprietary library (which most probably will be the origin of most changes, at least at the begining), and the open-source community, which changes could not (otherwise) be added to the proprietary version.

I would like to understand to which extends this is possible?

Comment: Requiring that the "AGPL or proprietary" header to be preserved all the time has some practical problems -- what if I start making changes to this file (as allowed by the AGPL). OK. But now, several versions down the line, does that mean someone else has the right to go back to you and ask for a proprietary license on my new version (which incorporates new code that I added under the AGPL?).  It seems a bit counterintuitive that that would be intended or possible.

Comment: The idea was that if you contribute, you agree that the proprietary version of it can pull your change. So yes, someone could ask for the proprietary license that includes your changes. My original idea was to make this same requirement on the proprietary license, and somehow avoiding divergence between the two licenses.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, it isn't possible.  AGPLv3 s7 precludes the addition of "*non-permissive additional terms*", and a requirement to dual-license under a proprietary licence definitely, to my mind, falls under that heading.  So anyone receiving your code under AGPLv3 could quite legitimately ignore that requirement.

You may certainly require a CLA from contributors to your codebase that permits this dual-relicensing, though it may (or may not) discourage people from contributing back to you.  But if someone takes your codebase and modifies it themselves, they are free to distribute it under simple AGPLv3, and there's nothing you can do to compel them to contribute those changes back to you with permission for later dual-licensing.  You can take the changes, but you'll take them under simple AGPLv3, and if you incorporate them in your code, you lose the right to dual-license.

It's your call: you can have the world help your develop your code, but if they choose not to accept your dual-license terms, you will have to choose between their help, and the dual-licensing scheme.

Comment: I was not understanding this as a non-permissive additional term, but rather a "let this guy do what he want with this code". But considering your rational, I have to admit that it makes sense. CLA will be. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Granting extra rights to a user is permissive.  *Requiring* that (s)he grants extra rights to his/her downstream users is restrictive.  And you're very welcome - good question, I thought.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DesertIslandTest is worth reading as it discusses requirement for contributing changes to original author.

Comment: He could draft such a license; but it becomes a unique license that's open source but definitely isn't free.

Comment: @Joshua: There is very little practical difference between open source and free. In this case, it *probably* violates [OSD](https://opensource.org/osd/) #5, because such a license gives more rights to the original upstream creator than it does to anyone else. This asymmetry is a (somewhat unusual) form of discrimination.

Comment: And I'll just hop in to remind people that [on this site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we use the OSI's definition of open-source, and the FSF's definition of free.  This is just to reinforce Kevin's first point above, and to head off any (off-topic) excursions into *source-available* land.